# Ordering divs from A-Z

Tags: jquery

I have a chat web page that has a DIV for each member. The DIV's look as follows:

```
 <div id="chatCenterMembers">
   <div id="lee" class="chatmember 10001"></div>
   <div id="arch" class="chatmember 10008"></div>
   <div id="steven" class="chatmember 10041"></div>
   <div id="tim" class="chatmember 10432"></div>
   <div id="ssan" class="chatmember 10007"></div>
   <div id="yanti" class="chatmember 10034"></div>
 </div>
```

Each of the "chatmember" DIV's have more content inside them - img, text etc.
How can I re-order the div's from A-Z using JQUERY?
I want to keep the contents with each DIV as it is - just move the ID to resemble A-Z.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get a collection of child `div` elements, and then use `sort()` to sort by their `id` attribute, and then append this to the container, effectively reordering them.

```
var parent = $('#chatCenterMembers');

parent.children('div').sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.id > b.id;
}).appendTo(parent);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Dfgn/).

Comment: @jAndy Does jQuery have a `sort()` method? I never knew that.

Comment: jQuery abstracts/copys the `Array.prototype.sort` into its own array-like object.

Comment: @jAndy, I'm pretty sure [jQuery doesn't have its own `sort` method](http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=sort). This appears to be using `Array.prototype.sort` directly.

Comment: @macek: ehhh, am I out of line here or did I just mentioned that in my previous comment ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's [a working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FUCLr/4/).

```
//Grab the parent container
var mylist = $('#chatCenterMembers');
//Get all the child div's in the parent
var listitems = mylist.children('div').get();

//Utilize the array.sort
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
    var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
    var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
    return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
});

$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) {
    mylist.append(itm);
});
```

Code taken from http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/02/25/sorting-elements-with-jquery/ and modified slightly.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
// get an array of DOM elements
var $elements = $('#chatCenterMembers div').get();

// sort the elements by ID
$elements.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.id === b.id) return 0;
    return a.id < b.id ? -1 : 1;
});

// append the elements
$('#chatCenterMembers').append($elements);
```

Answer (score 2):

Question is, order by what? Lets assume we'd like to order those by `classnames`, it'll look like:

```
var $members = $('#chatCenterMembers');

$members.children('div').detach().sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.className.localeCompare(b.className);
}).appendTo($members);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mCLxb/

We actually could omit the `.detach()` here, but for convenience it's probably nice to be in there.

Comment: +1 for `localCompare()`. @Adam, you should probably reconsider marking this as the correct answer.