# JQUERY Sorting an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array that is holding a number of  objects.

Array:

```
 var activeMembers=[];
```

The DIV objects in the above array look like as follows - each was added one at a time:

```
 <div id="mary" class="chatmember 1011"></div>
 <div id="steven" class="chatmember 1051"></div>
 <div id="adam" class="chatmember 1701"></div>
 <div id="bob" class="chatmember 1099"></div>
 <div id="peter" class="chatmember 1123"></div>
```

Is there a quick way to sort theses DIV objects in the array by the ID from A-Z?

thx

Comment: Didn't you ask this yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092266/ordering-divs-from-a-z

Comment: @Shervin maybe he just wondered where his question went ... and reasked it ... he's quite new to so, so give him a chance :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since there are so many silly implementations being proposed that are using jQuery when it is only a waste of resources, I'll propose my own.  This is just a straight javascript sort of an array by a property of the object in the array.  To do that you just use the array sort method with a custom comparison function that does an alpha comparison of the id value.  There is no reason or advantage to involve jQuery in this at all.

```
activeMembers.sort(function(a, b) {
   var aID = a.id;
   var bID = b.id;
   return (aID == bID) ? 0 : (aID > bID) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Note, as requested in the question, this sorts a list of div references in the array.  It does not sort the objects in the layout of the page.  To do that, you'd have to sort the references list, then rearrange the divs in the page according to the new array order.

If you can rely on the fact that no two IDs are ever the same in your own HTML (since you are never supposed to have two objects with the same ID), you can shorten and speed up the custom sort function to just be this:

```
activeMembers.sort(function(a, b) {
   return (a.id > b.id) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.chatmember').sort(function(a,b){ return a.id > b.id; })...
```

Returns (in Firebug):

```
[div#adam.chatmember, div#bob.chatmember, div#mary.chatmember, div#peter.chatmember, div#steven.chatmember]
```

Comment: There is no `sort` method in jQuery. Besides, that would only have any effect if the elements are also in the page, and it would only rearrange the elements in the page, not in the array.

Comment: @Guffa Sure about that? Might want to try running it before you start guessing. The elements don't move.

Comment: @Guffa but javascript knows `.sort()` (http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml)

Comment: @Stefan Mai: Sure about what? There doesn't exist any `sort` method in the documentation for jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=sort

Comment: @Guffa notice to myself: drink a cup of coffee, think/request for more information and then write ... sometimes it's really hard to follow this simple guide!

Comment: @Guffa Where did I say it was in jQuery or where did the author say it had to be jQuery exlusively? Supersets. Andreas explained this one. You said the elements would be rearranged, I ran it and it didn't. That's what I was asking you about.

Comment: @downvoter could you explain your downvote to give the author a chance for elaborating/fixing his answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
activeMembers.sort(function(a,b){
   var aid = $(a).attr('id');
   var bid = $(b).attr('id');

   return (aid==bid) ? 0 : (aid > bid) ? 1 : -1;

});
```

Comment: @downvoter could you explain your downvote to give the author a chance for elaborating/fixing his answer?

Comment: @jfriends, it stated on the tags of SO question

Comment: @jfriends, please note also that accessing of non-standard attributes with the use of obj.property may not work on all browsers, and the right way should be the obj.getAttribute(<name>) or the setAttribute. for instance if you have an <a> element that has rel attribute, you may not get the value using a.rel, using jquery .attr() handles this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no quick way.  You can use generic sorter that allow you to provide comparator, or you can write a custom sorter.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076844/jquery-sort-divs-by-classname) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tinysort plugin )(http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TinySort)

e.g.

```
$("#parentName > div").tsort("",{attr:"id"});
```

Comment: That will sort elements in the page, not an array.